# On extensions of fields and embeddings

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

This may be a simple doubt. As far as I know, when we say $K$ is a subfield of $L$, we mean that $K$ can be embedded in $L$ (through the embedding say $\phi$). Then, when I say, 'let $\alpha$ be in $L$ but not in $K$', I mean, $\alpha$ is not in the image of $\phi$.

Firstly, is it what the general understanding? Secondly, doesn't then the non-belongingness of $\alpha$ in $K$ depend on the embedding we choose? Can we have more than one injective maps from $K$ to $L$ in any circumstance? If so, why are we not stressing on the embedding we choose in the given situation of extensions?

For instance, suppose we consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathbb{Q}(a), \mathbb{Q}(b)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(c)$ be the three extensions obtained by adjoining the three roots $a(=\sqrt[3]{2}), b$ and $c$ of $p(x)$. Now, can't I embed $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ in $\mathbb{C}$ in two different ways? Firstly, we can directly treat $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ through the usual embedding. Secondly, I can treat $\mathbb{Q}(b)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ and then I would get a different embedding. Now in the first embedding I see that $b$ is in the image space while in the second it is not.

Am I thinking in right direction?

Comment: Sometimes, when people say $K$ is a subfield of $L$, they mean $K$ is a subset of $L$ and is a field under the operations inherited from $L$. With this definition, the question of embedding doesn't arise. But if we're using the definition you have given, it can still happen that there is no embedding of $K$ in $L$ such that $\alpha$ in $L$ is in the image of the embedding, and again there is no problem. In the case of the example you give, there is a genuine difficulty, and one should be careful to specify an embedding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can it happen that for a field $L$ in which $K$ is embedded in two different ways through $\phi$ and $\psi$ that some element $\alpha$ in $L$ is algebraic in the first case over $K$ and is not in the second?

Comment: The field $K(t)$ can be embedded in $K(x,y)$ by sending $t$ to $x$ or to $y$. The first way, $x$ is algebraic over $K(t)$, the other way, it's transcendental.

Comment: That's amazing which I never knew. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, when we say $K$ is a subfield of $L$, we mean that $K$ can be embedded in $L$ (through the embedding say $\phi$).

People play fast and loose with this terminology, but strictly speaking, no, this is not what this means. "$K$ is a subfield of $L$" means that $K$ is a *subset* of $L$ which is closed under the field operations. This is equivalent to saying that we have *fixed* an embedding of $K$ into $L$ but the point of insisting on $K$ being a literal subset is that it's totally unambiguous what it means for an element of $L$ to not be in $K$.

> Secondly, doesn't then the non-belongingness of $\alpha$ in $K$ depend on the embedding we choose?

It would in general, but we've fixed it.

People are sometimes sloppy about this sort of thing, but one reason it's possible to get away with this is the following:

> **Proposition:** If $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, then if an embedding $K \to L$ exists, its image is unique (although the embedding is not itself unique; different embeddings are related by the action of the Galois group $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$).

In this case, despite the fact that there are multiple embeddings, the meaning of "an element of $L$ not in $K$" is still unambiguous. For example there are two embeddings $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2 + 1) \to \mathbb{C}$ but they have the same image, namely the subfield $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ generated by $i$ (or $-i$). Your example of $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - 2)$ is ambiguous because it's not Galois.

Comment: The Galois Theory textbook by Ian Stewart defines subfield as Yathiraj says, not as a subset.

Comment: @qiaochu Yuan I understood. 'Fix the embedding'. The image being a subfield, we first may carry out our study of field extensions with the notion of subsets. However, later on, identifying a give field with a subfield of some other field depends on the embedding we choose and our language needs to be appropriately changed accordingly. Is it right?

Comment: That is, my doubt was, what does the term 'contained' mean in '$F$ is contained in $K$'?  What I knew was $F$ is identified with a subfield of $K$. Now, $F$ may be identified with different subfields of $K$ and accordingly the statements such as  $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$ change their meaning. Is it right?

Comment: @Yathiraj: yes, but again, in any particular such situation the embedding should be fixed.